# how to assign a returned array to an array on main()

Tags: c

I have a local array and im trying t return it and assign it to an array on the main() function

How would this work? I tried to do it this way but its not working

```
double fun(){

(....)


return array;

}



int main(){
(...) 
newfunction = fun();

}
```

Comment: Pass array to `fun` through a pointer.  For example, `double array[5]; fun(array);`

Comment: *I have a local array and im trying t return it ...*  What happens to a **local** variable when a function returns?

Comment: is there a way to do it without pointers? Because i haven't done that yet in my year of uni, Thank you for your response!

Comment: If you need return an array, then the class you are taking will have explained pointers. Why do you think you need to return an array? What is the actual assignment?

Comment: It didn't sadly, idk why we haven't being taught pointers yet, I am supposed to find the average of each line in a 2d array and return an array with all the averages

Comment: I suspect that a) you misunderstood your assignment (consider quoting it) b) we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem caused by that

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding, the assignment is not in english and i tried to translate it, thats basicallly what im being asked to do

Comment: In C, you can't assign to arrays (only to elements) and you can't return them as a whole. There are some hacks, like placing arrays into structs and returning structs, but that's not year 1 stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your response, ill just create the array on the function

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. If you have a solution to your problem - even if it is to refactor the code, it would be very helpful for other users if you could write it up as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is to pass the array as a parameter to the function:

```
void fun (double array[], size_t length) {
   for (unsigned i=0;i!=length;++i) {
       array[i] = (double)i;
   }
}

#define ARRAY_SIZE 5
int main(void) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    double array[ARRAY_SIZE];
    foo(array, ARRAY_SIZE);
    for (int i=0;i!=ARRAY_SIZE;++i) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    printf("sum: %lf\navg:\n", sum, sum/ARRAY_SIZE);
    return 0;
}
```

That should initialize the array in foo (with values from 0 to 4), and the main function then prints the sum and average of all elements.

Note: Technically, `double array[]` is equivalent to `double *array`, but you said you didn't know about pointers.